# Issue with fetching data from redux saga

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, response, redux-saga

Below is my code

/************ methods : http *******************/

/** http : Survey Quick Insights : get insights data**/

```
const httpGetSurveyQuickInsights = async (data) =>{
      await axios.post(baseUrl + URL_SURVEY_QUICK_INSIGHTS_GET_SURVEY_DETAILS,data,{timeout: 
       HTTP_TIMEOUT})
      .then(authUser => authUser)
      .catch(error => {
          return error
      });
```

}

/************ methods : http response handler *******************/

/** http : Survey Quick Insights List : http response handler **/

```
function* handleHttpGetSurveyQuickInsightsListResponse({payload}) {
    console.log("httpGetSurveyQuickInsights called")
    console.log(payload)
    console.log(payload.payload)
    try {
        let dataValue = yield call(httpGetSurveyQuickInsights, payload);
        if (dataValue.message) {
            yield put(getSurveyQuickInsightsError(dataValue.message));
        } else {
            yield put(surveyGetQuickInsights(dataValue.data));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(getSurveyQuickInsightsError(error));
    }
}
```

/************ methods : export access *******************/

/** Survey quick insights : get all records **/

```
export function* getSurveyQuickInsightsList() {
    yield takeEvery(SURVEY_ANALYSE_RESULTS_GET_QUICKINSIGHTS, 
    handleHttpGetSurveyQuickInsightsListResponse);
}



export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        fork(getSurveyQuickInsightsList)
    ]);
}
```

I am getting the dataValue as empty. What could be the fix for this?

Comment: did you run in postman with these parameters to ensure the API does have any data corresponding to your request and also check the network tab to see if any information is there on the request

Comment: I am able to get the response in postman and also data is showing up in the network